# How do I use tryNext() in Gremlin with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, gremlin

The following example does not work for me in Node.js using the 'gremlin' 3.4.1 npm package:

```
g.V().has('person','name','bill').tryNext().orElseGet{g.addV('person').property('name','bill').next()}
```

I am getting a TypeError saying `tryNext()` is not a function. What am I doing wrong?

```
import {driver, structure} from 'gremlin';
import DriverRemoteConnection = driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
import Graph = structure.Graph;

const g = new Graph().traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'));

console.log(g.V().toList());    <= working
```

Now using the line from above in that code will not work, but it does work using the Gremlin console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `tryNext()` not supported as Dave mentioned.

You can rewrite your query to do the same with other gremlin steps:

```
g.V().has('person','name','bill').fold().coalesce(unfold(),g.addV('person').property('name','bill')).next()
```

Comment: I got unfold is not defined error, how to fix that?

Comment: Sound not likely that ````unfold```` not supported. Did you run the same query here?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to call a function that doesn't exist, which appears to be as stated in the Gremlin docs, to wit:

> `tryNext()` will return an `Optional` and thus, is a composite of `hasNext()`/`next()` (only supported for JVM languages).

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#terminal-steps

*Caveat: Never used TinkerPop, never used Gremlin. But I know how to use the web. Could be this is wrong, but the docs do seem fairly clear.*